# Blazor/OpenCv js : Error: MONO_WASM: Module.ready couldn't be redefined

Tags: javascript, opencv, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I am currently working on a Blazor component that requires opencv.
I've added `opencv.js` (4.8.0) in `wwwroot`.

Here is my html file:

```html
<script async src="_content/MyComponent/opencv.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

I keep getting the following error :

```
Failed to start platform. Reason: Error: MONO_WASM: Module.ready couldn't be redefined.
    at Vt (blazor.webassembly.js:1:62226)
```

I am very new to Blazor/Js and since I don't really understand how wasm works under the hood, it's hard for me to even understand the error.

Any documentation or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because you are using Blazor WASM you also have the option of using [OpenCVSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed my issue:

1. Open 'opencv.js' and replace the laste 4 lines as follows

```js
  if (typeof Module === 'undefined')
    Module = {};
  return cv(Module);
}));
```

replace with

```js
  if (typeof OpenCvModule === 'undefined')
    OpenCvModule = {};
  return cv(OpenCvModule);
}));
```

`Module` variable is apparently conflicting between Blazor's wasm and opencv.

Side note: to make sure that your script gets reloaded in your browser, rename it (do not forget the html file). Blazor's cache handling could be really annoying.